# What are the correct scopes to use for different applications?

Tags: api, rest-api, security, permissions

I am writing a desktop application (or several) to access mail, contacts and chat via the REST api ([User-Agent Flow](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Native_Application_.28User-Agent_Flow.29))

What are the correct and minimal scopes to use for each of these individually or for all three in one go?

I have found [this page](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm) but it is not quite clear enough.

Current thoughts would be:

All: `api refresh_token`

Mail: `api refresh_token`

Contacts: `api refresh_token`

Chat: `chatter_api refresh_token`

Is there any need for `full`?

Do I have to pass `refresh_token` with everything or is it included in eg. `api`?

It says on the page that `id` is implicit in everything so is there any need to send it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `api` gives you access to all the user's data via the APIs. Definitely gives you Contacts, and I believe it gives you SendEmail also. Note that `api` also gives you access to Chatter, so you don't need to specify both. `chatter_api`, on the other hand, gives you access to the Chatter API, but no other APIs.

I don't think you need `full` - as far as I know, that's just a synonym for `api web visualforce`, which transitively includes `id chatter_api`.

Yes, you will need to specify `refresh_token` with everything - it's not included in any other scope.

You don't need to send `id` if you're specifying any other scope - it's only useful if you need to access the identity service only.